# On checkout woocommerce send always 0 price & paypal extension not working

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

I have issue with woocommerse and paypal extension. It was working fine before update. When i checkout using woocommerce then paypal always pick up 0 price as total price.

Please help Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What extension are you using from WooCommerce? Could you try using the plugin below instead?

https://www.angelleye.com/product/woocommerce-paypal-plugin/

Regards,
Jeremy

Comment: Thanks but it was sorted out by replacing the woocommerce plugin with another.